# Перевести массив

Tags: java, массивы

Каким образом массив int (2,3,4,5,6,7) перевести в double (2.0,3.0,4.0 ...)?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Так:

```
public static double[] copyFromIntArray(int[] source) {
    double[] dest = new double[source.length];
    for(int i=0; i<source.length; i++) {
        dest[i] = source[i];
    }
    return dest;
}
```

Или так:

```
public static double[] copyFromIntArray(int[] source) {
    return Doubles.toArray(Ints.asList(source));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Средствами Java 8 без дополнительных библиотек:

```
public static double[] toDoubles(int[] source) {
    return IntStream.of(source).asDoubleStream().toArray();
}
```